# Insert tuple in sqlite request

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I have `selected_comments` which is a tuple of id that I want to remove from the sqlite3 database. I tried this command (and other variations):

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM comments WHERE id IN (?)",(selected_comments))
```

But I get errors (for this specific command, I have: `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied.`).

The size of the tuple is not fixed: it can go from 1 element to as much as you want.

Comment: did you try putting it as just `selected_comments` and not `(selected_comments)`?

Comment: Yes. And with `?` as well.

Comment: Have you tried ``(selected_comments,)`` instead of ``(selected_comments)``.

Comment: It was my first try. But `selected_comments` is already a tuple, so there is no need to add the comma.